# How to debug a custom activity in journey builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I created a custom activity that is hosted in Azure, I was able to put it in a journey builder and activate it. Now in the config.json file there are multiple end points and I want to do some debugging and check the flow of the code if it's working. I can't seem to find a way to do this.

This is the sample of my config.json file

```json
{
"workflowApiVersion": "1.0",
"metaData": {
    "icon": "images/icon.png",
    "iconSmall": "images/iconSmall.png",
    "category": "custom",
    "version": "2.0"
},

"type": "Rest",
"lang": {
    "en-US": {
        "name": "Send Request",
        "description": "Testing of sending request"
    }

},

"arguments": {
    "execute": {
        "inArguments": [], 
        "outArguments": [], 
        "url": "urlHostedInAzure/journeybuilder/execute",
        "verb": "POST",
        "body": "", 
        "header": "", 
        "format": "json",
        "useJwt": false,
        "timeout": 10000
    }

},
"configurationArguments": {
    "applicationExtensionKey": "aed95997-1805-43a8-b642-c6336a77e776",
    "save": {
        "url": "urlHostedInAzure/journeybuilder/save",
        "body": "", 
        "verb": "POST",
        "useJwt": false
    },
    "publish": {
        "url": "urlHostedInAzure/journeybuilder/publish",
        "verb": "POST",
        "body": "", 
        "useJwt": false
    },
    "validate": {
        "url": "urlHostedInAzure/journeybuilder/validate",
        "verb": "POST",
        "body": "", 
        "useJwt": false
    }
},
"userInterfaces":
{
    "configModal": {
        "height": 700,
        "width": 1000,
        "fullscreen": false
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Changes in your config will not help you debug your code. You need to add logging statements to the code of your endpoints. How this is done depends on the programming language you use. Maybe there is even the possibility to add breakpoints and debug through the code using debugging software.

Without supplying your code and environment details this general answer is all thats possible right now.

I suggest you go ahead and try to find tutorials specific to debugging the programming language your backend/endpoint is written in.

Comment: I forget to mention that I have console.log in my code. I was able to see the debugs in the Azure Logs.

Comment: In that case you just need to output the relevant information like the request payload and headers, so you see what information you get from Marketing Cloud. In addition the relevant variables in your endpoints could be logged at certain points in your control flow.