# Where i can see jwt token passed or not to end points in journey builder custom activity

Tags: custom, jwt, activity

Where I can see jwt token passed or not to end points in journey builder custom activity, JWT not included in payload for Custom Activity endpoints

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to debug a custom activity in journey builder](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/278481/how-to-debug-a-custom-activity-in-journey-builder)

Comment: If the useJwt property is set to true for any of the REST activity's methods, then a JWT for the account is generated, encoded, and sent as the POST body. Where i can check jwt value in heroku logs